# Wait till setImageWithURL is loaded SDWebImage

Tags: ios, caching, uiimageview, uiimage, sdwebimage

What i need is to wait till `setImageWithURL` has finished proccesing the image, here is my code on the viewDidLoad method:

```
UIImageView *test = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[test setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:object.imageUrl]];
```

Is there anyway to set this method to run synchronous? I have tried the `completed` block, but for some strange reason it never gets called.

Comment: The api contains a couple varieties of this call that include completion blocks.  I can't think of any upside to running it synchronously.  http://hackemist.com/SDWebImage/doc/Categories/UIImageView(WebCache).html

Comment: the completed block never gets called

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember SDWebImage doesn't have methods to download/set image synchronously (for obvious reasons). But if your use case wants you to use a synchronous method, try this:

```
UIImageView *test = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];
[test setImage:image];
```

Hope this helps.